# Objective C isEqual not evaluating when comparing int and id

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to implement binary search in Objective C. I am mainly struggling with this line of code `if ([searchItem isEqual:midElement]){` because it's evaluating to be true when the values are different `searchItem = 1` and `midElement = 4`:

```
@implementation NSArray (BinarySearch)

- (NSInteger) binarySearch : (id) searchItem {
    NSLog(@"SearchItem: %@", searchItem);
    return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:0 max:[self count] - 1];
}

- (NSInteger) binarySearch:(id)searchItem min:(NSInteger)min max:(NSInteger)max {
    if (max < min) {
        return NSNotFound;
    }

    NSInteger mid = (max + min) / 2;
    id midElement = [self objectAtIndex:mid];
    NSLog(@"Search Item: %d, Current Value: %@, Min: %d, Mid: %d, Max: %d", searchItem, midElement, min, mid ,max);

    NSLog(@"IsEqual: %d", [searchItem isEqual:midElement]);


    if ([searchItem isEqual:midElement]){
        return mid;
    }
    else if (searchItem < midElement){
        return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:min max:mid];
    }
    else{
        return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:mid max:max];
    }
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *orderedList = @[@1, @2, @4, @7, @8, @10];
        NSLog(@"Binary search on a list: %d", [orderedList binarySearch: 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code output:

```
SearchItem:
Search Item: 1, Current Value: 4, Min: 0, Mid: 2, Max: 5
IsEqual: 1
Binary search on a list: 2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Edit for Genecode, when I changed it to this:

```
NSInteger mid = (max + min) / 2;
int midElement = [self objectAtIndex:mid];
NSLog(@"Search Item: %d, Current Value: %@, Min: %d, Mid: %d, Max: %d", searchItem, midElement, min, mid ,max);

NSLog(@"IsEqual: %d", searchItem == midElement);


if (searchItem == midElement){
    return mid;
}
```

`searchItem == midElement` evaluates to zero no matter what. Code output:

```
SearchItem:
Search Item: 1, Current Value: 4, Min: 0, Mid: 2, Max: 5
IsEqual: 0
Search Item: 1, Current Value: 2, Min: 0, Mid: 1, Max: 2
IsEqual: 0
Search Item: 1, Current Value: 1, Min: 0, Mid: 0, Max: 1
IsEqual: 0
Binary search on a list: -1
```

Comment: It would be easier to typecase the id into int and compare int to int normally IMHO.

Comment: @GeneCode, please checkout the edit.

Comment: Do you get any build warnings?

Comment: @Willeke only formatting, but this could be useful: https://imgur.com/a/DId3h9A

Comment: So `NSLog` isn't logging what you think it's logging. Fix all build warnings, you can't compare integers to `NSNumber`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from what `@1` *actually is* in Objective-C.  It *is not* an `NSInteger`.  It is a literal shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`.  i.e. it creates an object.

You are then attempting to compare an NSInteger with an object reference and, not surprisingly, it doesn't work.

In fact, this line:

```
NSLog(@"Binary search on a list: %d", [orderedList binarySearch: 1]);
```

Should give you an error and a warning that indicates the issue:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed under ARC
>   Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'

By recognising that you are actually dealing with objects and using the `compare` method you get:

```
@implementation NSArray (BinarySearch)

- (NSInteger) binarySearch : (id) searchItem {
    NSLog(@"SearchItem: %@", searchItem);
    return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:0 max:[self count] - 1];
}

- (NSInteger) binarySearch:(id)searchItem min:(NSInteger)min max:(NSInteger)max {


    if (max-min < 2) {
        return NSNotFound;
    }

    NSInteger mid = (max + min) / 2;

    NSNumber *midElement = [self objectAtIndex:mid];
    NSLog(@"Search Item: %@, Current Value: %@, Min: %ld, Mid: %ld, Max: %ld", searchItem, midElement, min, mid ,max);

    NSComparisonResult result = [midElement compare:searchItem];

    switch (result) {
        case NSOrderedSame:
            return mid;
            break;

        case NSOrderedAscending:
            return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:mid max:max];
            break;

        case NSOrderedDescending:
            return [self binarySearch:searchItem min:min max:mid];
            break;
    }

}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *orderedList = @[@1, @2, @4, @7, @8, @10];
            NSLog(@"Binary search on a list: %ld", [orderedList binarySearch: @7]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output

> SearchItem: 7
>
> Search Item: 7, Current Value: 4, Min: 0, Mid: 2, Max: 5
>
> Search Item: 7, Current Value: 7, Min: 2, Mid: 3, Max: 5
>
> Binary search on a list: 3
>
> Program ended with exit code: 0

You also had a problem with your termination condition that would result in infinite recursion if the item wasn't found.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a scalar integer `1` to `-binarySearch:`, which treats it as an object pointer `id`. You need to pass `@1` or another `NSNumber*` (at least an object pointer).

Also, since `searchItem` is an object pointer, you should log it with `%@`, not `%d` (as the warning was trying to tell you). The only reason that `%d` didn't crash is because of the other bug. The two bugs canceled each other out.

You should **not** use `<` to compare two objects by value. That compares their addresses, which is generally meaningless. You should use `-compare:` rather than `-isEqual:` or `<`.

Answer (score 0):

How is isEqual: Implemented, also your < operator is not likely going to give you what you want, you are trying to compare to objects, objective-c doesn’t support operator overloading, if you want to implement your own binary search, look at implementing a compare: method that can return a value telling you how two objects should be ordered, that way you only have one method call instead of two which is more efficient. Better still, NSArray has a method called indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:, which can be passed an option to do a binary search for you.

Comment: oh sweet! im just trying to learn obj c by implementing data structures and basic algos but that's good to know.

Comment: Lots of classes like NSNumber, NSDate implement a method called compare: that returns NSComparisonResult, NSString implement more than one compare method that return NSComparisonResult results, so if you have your own class I would create your own compare: method to return a NSComparisonResult. You can then use NSComparisonResult to determine order.